# Сложная функция в EXCEL

Tags: excel

Задание по статистическому анализу. Дано n-ное количество чисел, заданы интервалы, (например, 3 интервала: 1 - 5, 5 - 10, 10 - 15) как правильно записать в ячейку под каждым интервалом функцию, в которой будет количество чисел, входящих в этот интервал, с условием больше или равно меньшего числа и меньше большего числа?
Моя функция `"=СЧЁТЕСЛИМН(A1:O9;">С20";A1:O9;"<=С21"`)" дает результат в ноль, хотя есть числа в этом интервале.

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем варианте записи С20 - не ссылка. Заключено в кавычки - текст.

```
=СЧЁТЕСЛИМН(A1:O9;">"&С20;A1:O9;"<="&С21)
```

В Excel-2003 СЧЕТЕСЛИМН еще не было. Для этой версии можно пригласить на помощь обычную СЧЕТЕСЛИ:

```
=СЧЁТЕСЛИ(A1:O9;">"&С20)-СЧЕТЕСЛИ(A1:O9;">"&С21)
```

Если формула протягиваемая, нужно закрепить диапазон: *$A$1:$O$9*

Comment: Все равно выходит неверно, опять же результат в ноль.
___
Выходит верно только тогда, когда вместо ячеек С20 и С21 я ввожу сами цифры, но это крайне неудобно.